# Get an error, when passing bool variable in my own style file

Tags: packages, kvoptions

I wrote a package to customize my footnotes. For now only one feature matters: I want to give a bool parameter to change the font of my footnotes.

The style file looks like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{AFWfnotetext}[2019/07/07 v1.1 A footnotes]

\RequirePackage{sectsty}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family=AFW,
    prefix=AFW@
}%

\DeclareBoolOption[true]{condensed}
%\ProcessLocalKeyvalOptions*


\let\oldfootnote\footnote

\ifAFW@condensed
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\footnote}{ O{} m }
    {\oldfootnote{\textcn{#2}}}
\else
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\footnote}{ O{} m }
    {\oldfootnote{#2}}
\fi

\ExecuteOptions{condensed}

\ProcessOptions\relax
```

Not passing the condensed value in my preamble of my document works fine, but when I use: `\usepackage[condensed=true]{AFWfnotetext}` in my document I get the following message:

```
Unknown option `condensed=true' for package `AFWfnotetext'. \ProcessOptions\relax
```

I am new to programming in LaTeX and could not figure out what is going on.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel does not support key value options. Therefore, there are packages like
`kvoptions` that you have used. Then, instead of `\ProcessOptions` that does not know about key value options, the package command like `\ProcessKeyvalOptions` should be used.

`\ExecuteOptions{condensed}` does not make sense here, because `\DeclareBoolOption[true]{condensed}` already initalizes the option with `true`.

The order of option declaration, usage and option actions are out of order.

- First: The options are defined (`\SetKeyvalOptions`, `\DelareBoolOption`).
- Second: The options are processed (`\ProcessOptions`)
- Third: In the evaluation phase, the code is executed depending on the option values (`\ifAFW@condensed`).

Comment: Thanks. The version of @egreg works too, but is less intuitive (at least to me). I hat to change `\ProcessKeyvalOptions` to `\ProcessKeyvalOptions*` because else I get the same error plus `Paragraph ended before \KVO@ProcessKeyvalOptions was complete.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `l3keys2e`:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{AFWfnotetext}[2019/07/07 v1.1 A footnotes]

\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { AFWfnotetext }
 {
  condensed .bool_set:N = \g_AFWfnotetext_condensed_bool,
  condensed .default:n  = true,
  condensed .initial:n  = true,
 }

\ProcessKeysPackageOptions { AFWfnotetext }

\cs_set_eq:cc { latex@footnotetext } { @footnotetext }

\bool_if:NT \g_AFWfnotetext_condensed_bool
 {
  \cs_set:Npn \@footnotetext #1 { \latex@footnotetext{\textit[#1}} }
 }
```

Note: I used `\itshape` because I don't know about `\textcn` (the package should provide the definition).

Here is a test file, with reduced text height for making a smaller picture. Note that the optional argument to `\footnote` can be used, which it cannot with your approach.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
%  condensed,
%  condensed=true,
  condensed=false,
]{AFWfnotetext}

\setlength{\textheight}{4cm}

\begin{document}

Test\footnote{Test for footnotes}

Test\footnote[4]{Another test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output with `condensed`, `condensed=true` or no option at all, is

[image]

Comment: Hey to be honest I do't get what happens in your code but it helps :). Did your code work out exactly this way? Because I had to change `{\itshape#1}` to `{\itshape{#1}}`. Your version only affected the first letter of my footnotes.

Comment: @Pibe_chorro Did you use `\itshape` or `\textcn`? I modified the code: `\textZZ` type macros require an argument.

Comment: I tried both. `\textcn` is just a command I defined in elsewhere to use a condensed font.